# How can I use Linq to get distinct results filtered by property

Tags: c#, linq

Given this class:

```
public class Tool
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
    }
```

And a list of Tools like this:

```
var tools = new List<Tool>()
            {
                new Tool {Id=444, Number=121, Source="Master"},
                new Tool {Id=777, Number=121, Source="M1"},
                new Tool {Id=333, Number=51, Source="Master"},
                new Tool {Id=555, Number=61, Source="Master"},
                new Tool {Id=848, Number=51, Source="M1"}
                //Many more
            };
```

How could I use Linq to get a list of distinct Tools by Number and if 2 tools have the same Number select the one whose source is "M1", i.e.the resulting list would contain:

```
Tool {Id=777, Number=121, Source="M1"}
Tool {Id=848, Number=51, Source="M1"}
Tool {Id=555, Number=61, Source="Master"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Tool> distinctTool = tools
  .GroupBy(p => p.Number)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(q => q.Source == "M1").First())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try grouping by Number and get the first element of that,

```
List<Tool> distinctTool = tools.GroupBy(p => p.Number)
                               .Select(f => f.OrderByDescending(q => q.Source == "M1").First())
                               .ToList();
```

**[`WORKING FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qF2qV)**

Comment: This does not deal with prioritizing the `M1` source

Comment: ok ok guys!  it happens:)

Comment: @JamesFaix Corrrected

Comment: You still need to update your query to Group By with `Number`, not with `Source` . its giving the wrong results.

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir Thanks for that correction, that was my initial answer

Comment: Welcome , It happens :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to group your `Tools` by Number and get the `First()` of them

```
List<Tool> distinctTool = tools
  .GroupBy(p => p.Number)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(q => q.Source == "M1").First())      
  .ToList();
```